# Creating a list showing how many posts every user has posted on site

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working (or better I'm learning) in django, i want to create an html page with a list that shows how many posts every user has published so far.

in views.py i set:

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff) #<-Because I want that only admin will see this
def num_post(request):
    num_post = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user).count()
    return render(request, 'api/post_numbers.html', {'num_post' : num_post})
```

and in post_numbers.html i set:

```
{{user.username}} : {{ num_post }}
```

but i can only obtain the name and the post number of the current user...

how can i solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request.user` represents your current user which is authenticated and in case the session is not authenticated it will be AnonymousUser.

```
num_post = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user).count()
```

So when you query this it will show number of posts of current user only.

```
from django.db.models import Count

@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff) #<-Because I want that only admin will see this
def num_post(request):
    num_post = dict(Post.objects.values_list('author__username').annotate(Count('id')))
    return render(request, 'api/post_numbers.html', {'num_post' : num_post})
```

template

```
{% for username, num in num_post.items %}
  <li>{{ username }} : {{ num }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! i get unresolved reference error on "Count"

Comment: @Aokami Can you give more details about your code and the traceback error. Have you imported from django.db.models import Count. Let me edit my answer and try it

Comment: Great! it works very well. It displays only users that actually published at least one post. is there a way to display even those who have 0 active posts?

Comment: @Aokami Annotate on the User model for the post. You will get the number of post for every user. Also, don't forget to upvote the answer if you find it useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

views.py : User being your user model.

```
 @user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff) 
    def num_post(request):
        
        users  = User.objects.all()
        for user in users:
            user.num_post = Post.objects.filter(author=user).count()
        context = {'users':users}
        return render(request, 'api/post_numbers.html', context=context)
```

template

```
{% for user in users %}
   {{user.username}} : {{ user.num_post }}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
This give me an error on the template rendering:
Exception type: TypeError
Exception Value: object of type "User" has no len()

I copied exactly the code you posted, and checked many times for eventually typo.
Thank you so much for the help <3